# How to get URL hit by user in Spring security config file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, spring-security

Im working in a java-springs web application with custom security evaluator method,
i need to pass the URL hit by user as a parameter for the method permissionEvaluator.canUserAccessPage(URLHitByUser).

How to get URL hit by user.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
    .authorizeRequests()
        //.antMatchers("/view/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/view/admin.html").access("@permissionEvaluator.canUserAccessPage(URLHitByUser)")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/index") 
        .permitAll() 

    // [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intention is controlling the access to certain roles,this can be achieved by using sec:intercept-url in applicationContext-security-preauth.xml.

Thanks

Comment: But i have seventy html files and sixty roles.
the roles and access can be modified dynamically, and available in DB.
so i wrote a method boolean canUserAccessPage(StringURL); 
this method returns true or false by querying DB using user code logged in and URL hit by user.

So it will be help full if the URL can be retrieved.

Thanks.